# My bridge is out of place

Tags: electric-guitar, strings, maintenance, repair

My bridge keeps tilting and causing buzz. Is there some way to fix this?

[image: bridge]

Comment: Do you mean you have tried adjusting the saddle screws (As shown https://youtu.be/1dEZxBykRto?t=605) but they still keep tilting?

Comment: See those two legs that each saddle stands on? A small Allen key (1~1.5mm) will fit into the top of it. If you turn it, the saddle will move up/down. Search "strat setup" on YouTube.

Comment: Wild guess - thread is stripped on one 'leg'. If you adjust it correctly & it drops back again, you need a new saddle.

Comment: One of the three of you should make all of that an answer and add something like 'if that doesn't work, consult a luthier and have it replaced.' ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem in the past on one of my bridge saddles. My method of stopping it from happening repeatedly was to use Loctite thread dressing. I put a drop of Loctite on a disposable piece of paper, then removed the offending screw from the bridge saddle and dipped it into the drop of Loctite. With the threads of the screw still wet with Loctite, I reassembled it into the bridge saddle, wiped away the excess Loctite, adjusted the bridge saddle to where it needs to be and then set it aside to let the Loctite setup. I haven't had any more trouble with the bridge saddle since then. I hope this helps.